# UIScrollview with section animation like UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am currently working with an app that would generate a report from the user. These reports would be displayed on a scroll view. I would like the scrollview to look like the photo feed of Instagram (please see Instagram app on iOS). This would be doable using UITableView since the section sticks up above while scrolling the row. I want to achieve the same effect using only UIScrollView. Is this doable? Please let me know your advice.

Comment: i feel that table view is better in this way you should used it . and section stick problem can be managed using contentinset.

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView+TPKeyboardAvoidingAdditions
TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView
TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView
UIScrollView+TPKeyboardAvoidingAdditions

Download these custom classes from Github and follow the procedure given there !